# Amplifier voltage gain

Tags: transistors, amplifier, small-signal

How to determine the voltage gain and input/output impedance of the following circuit given that R1=273.56 and R2=2325?
I have been trying to calculate the voltage gain through solving small signal ac analysis (Hybrid-pi model) but eventually wasn't able to find the solution.
Do we have to follow any systematic approach in order to solve such problems?
[image]

Comment: The small-signal model IS the systematic approach for circuits which are not "standard" circuits analyzed in most textbooks (e.g., common-emitter, etc.). Here, I'd suggest breaking up the circuit into parts and trying the analysis that way first. For instance, the (AC) output impedance is unlikely to matter much to the left of that infinite capacitor, because the 45kOhm resistor to ground and the Q2 collector will have a much higher impedance than R2 (which can be treated as going from the base of Q3 to a virtual ground for AC analysis). That chunk is a tractable problem.

Comment: Without spending time and just scanning quickly, it looks like an emitter follower (no gain to speak of) being used to drive the low impedance input of the following common base (can have voltage gain here) followed by an emitter follower (no gain to speak of, but again a current gain.) So you need to analyze the \$Q_2\$ circuit if you are interested in the voltage gain.

Comment: Are you sure about R2 value? Also, notice that Q1 and Q2 can be seen as a differential amplifier from a small-signal perspective. And from which book, you have this problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my calculations.I have checked my procedure again. VB3=0.7 and IB3 =0.004 which leads to R2=75.Am I doing something wrong? @G36

Comment: But 0.7V is not a voltage drop across R2 resistor. What is the voltage drop across R2 resistor?

Comment: Thanks , yes you are right R2 is 2325 KOhm. @G36

Comment: Much better now. Now try to find the voltage gain.